# How do I translate dataframe column with multiple languages to English without getting: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests

Tags: python, dataframe, google-colaboratory, google-translate, textblob

```
 Unnamed: 0  rating                                             review
0              0       4  Biggest disappointement ever. It was supposed ...
1              1       4  Destiny is not innovative. This game was alrea...
2              2       2  I was able to play the beta with a couple frie...
3              3       4  I liked the intro, sadly it was all downhill f...
4              4       2  Embrace yourself for Activision $500 million w...
...          ...     ...                                                ...
1765        1765       2  It tried so hard and it got so far. Destiny is...
1766        1766       4  Extremely over hyped. It left me feeling meh. ...
1767        1767       5  The positive reviews here are basically trying...
1768        1768       6  You can absolutely tell that this game is from...
1769        1769       0  Woulda gave this an honest 5, but Bungie score...
```

The above dataframe, as well as other dataframes need to have the reviews converted from multiple languages to English. Through looking online I was told to use the following code:

```
from time import sleep
from textblob import TextBlob
from textblob.exceptions import NotTranslated    

def translate_comment(x):
    try:
        # Try to translate the string version of the comment
        return TextBlob(str(x)).translate(to='en')
    except NotTranslated:
        # If the output is the same as the input just return the TextBlob version of the input
        return TextBlob(str(x))

for i in range(len(df2['review'])):
    # Translate one comment at a time
    df2['review'].iloc[i] = translate_comment(df2['review'].iloc[i])

    # Sleep for a quarter of second
    sleep(0.25)
```

However, this presented me with the following error:

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
```

Through looking online I have seen that sleep time can change this, but I have been able to change it and think it's unlikely that the method will work. Does anyone have a fix to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It only allows about 100 requests per one hour period and there after returns a 429 error (Too many requests). On the other hand, the Google Translate Api has a default billable limit of 5 requests/second/user and 200,000 requests/day."